# SQL can I make something like Implode in PHP?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new.
I have a table like this

```
table t_student
 ------------------------------------------
| student_class  |  student_id  | name1    | 
| 01             |  01          | Thanh1   |
| 01             |  02          | Thanh2   |
| 01             |  03          | Thanh3   |
 ------------------------------------------
```

and I group by `student_class` to get a view like this

```
view v_student
 --------------------------------------------------------
| student_id  |  student_class  | name1                  | 
| 01          |  01-02-03       | Thanh1-Thanh2-Thanh3   | 
 --------------------------------------------------------
```

My question is : any way to select in SQL to get back the table when I just have only the view ?

It is ok when I search in the view `v_student` with operator `~* 'Thanh2'` in `name1` column

But when I search with `~* '^Thanh2$'`, there is no search result,
I want to have one result when search with `~* '^Thanh2$'` in the view `v_student`, is it possible ?

Please help me, Thank you so much.

**Edit:**

View code:

```
select a.student_class,
       array_to_string(array_agg(a.student_id), '-'::text) AS student_id, 
       array_to_string(array_agg(a.name1), '-'::text) AS name1
from (select * from t_student order by student_class,student_id) a
group by a.student_class
```

Comment: Unrelated but: `array_to_string(array_agg(...)` can be replaced with `string_agg()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you provided above, I wouldn't expect you to get a match with the regex `~* '^Thanh2$'`, as that means the string is **exactly** *Thanh2*, since `^` is the beginning anchor and `$` is the end anchor, and your view has apparently combined all three names into one string. Therefore, that regex would not match.

In contrast, `~* 'Thanh2'` is looking for that substring anywhere in the string, so that will match even the combined values in the view.

It looks like the view is mashing the group values together into arrays and joining them together with a dash (not quite sure offhand what the utility of such a view would be, but I'll assume you find it useful in your scenario). In that case, one could do something like this to get the name values back out into an array to then use in the table, which would work **if and only if** each dash-delimited item was unique.

```
select regexp_split_to_array(name1, E'-')
from v_student;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/553c4/2/1)

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

I'm not a PHP guy, but based on the doc for [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), the definition of your view is essentially using the *Postgres* equivalent -- `array_to_string`.

The opposite of that -- explode, if you will -- would be what I included in my answer, `regexp_split_to_array`, which allows you to get the values back out again.

Since `t_student` exists -- it's being queried in the view defintion -- why not simply query it directly?

Comment: Thank you @Ken Hampson                                           
But I want to ask that can I make an SQL to get something like t_student from v_student ?                 
so I can change my search place to the result table with ~* '^Thanh2$'

Comment: Usually views transform tables, so `v_student` would transform `t_student`. Is that not the case for your database? What's the code for `v_student`?

Comment: select 
   a.student_class,
   array_to_string(array_agg(a.student_id), '-'::text) AS student_id,
   array_to_string(array_agg(a.name1), '-'::text) AS name1   
from 
   (select * from t_student order by student_class,student_id) a
group by   
   a.student_class

Comment: Hi @Ken Hampson
Thank to your regexp_split_to_array I think I find the way for my problem.
Thank you so much my first helper :D